# Skip printing the first value of array in jquery data tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

this is a response from the api

```
{"recordsTotal":13,"data":[[13,"wretwer","rgsdfg","sdfgsd",null],[12,"heyh","gffsf","sfgsdf",null],[11,"sdfgwt","hdgdhsf","sfgsf",null],[10,"ethgs","fgsdfgsfd","dfsgdf",null],[9,"ertyyh","dgfsfg","sdfgs",null],[8,"yuyet","ertg","hdghd",null],[7,"dfgs","wtwr","sdfg",null],[6,"tyueyt","etyetye","erty",null],[5,"qerqe","qwer","qwerqwer",null],[4,"d","d","ggsss",null],[3,"asdf","asdf","asdf",null],[2,"asdfasd","asdfasdf","asdfadsf",null],[1,"test","asdf","34asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf",null]]}
```

I want to skip printing the first value of array that is 13 or 12 ....

this is what i have got so far

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#appartment-table").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/datatable/apartments",
        "columns": [
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null, 
            {"mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<a href="apartments/'+row[0]+'/edit">Edit</a>';}
                    }         
     ]
    });
});
```

Comment: simple:- don't send it from php end (server end)

Comment: i need it for editing and del

Comment: Well then switch from using `ajax` to `data` in your `DataTable` initialization - and make your own AJAX request to fetch the data, and manipulate it the way you want before that ...

Comment: @CBroe gotcha, thanks will try to do that.

Comment: @CBroe Not necessary to refactor http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1007/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick which columns to show by the array indexes :

```
columns: [
  { data: 1 },
  { data: 2 },
  { data: 3 },
  { data: 4,
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
       return '<a href="apartments/'+row[0]+'/edit">Edit</a>';
    }
  }         
 ]
```

Will skip the first element in the arrays, 13, 12 ...Remember to adjust the columns in `<thead>` accordingly (if you are using a static thead and not let DT create it by using `column.title`)